# Is it encouraged to use method variable rather than class variable for unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Should we try using method 2 when writing function inside class to decouple function from the class variables so that we can better unit test the individual function? Is it a good practice always pass class variable to class function as method parameters?

```
 public class User 
 {
     public string  BirthOfMonth = string.Empty;
     public string  BirthOfDay = string.Empty;

     public MyClass(string month, string day)
     {
         this.BirthOfMonth = month;
         this.BirthOfDay = day;
     }

     // method 1
     public string GetUserBirthday() {
         return BirthOfMonth +"/" + BirthOfDay;
     }

     // method 2
     public string GetUserBirthday(string month, string day) {
         return month +"/" +day;
     }
}
```

It is common in a class method to reference class members (as in method 1 above)? Or is it always better to pass those members as method parameters (a in method 2 above), instead of directly using them inside method?

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont fully understand your question.  Would you mind restating it?

Comment: You're coming from C#, so remember that Java has some differences: the string class is `String`, and the Java equivalent of C#'s `string.Empty` is `""`. Also the convention for variables and methods is to start with lowercase (only classes start with uppercase). And `BirthOfMonth` should be `monthOfBirth` :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you pass variables that belong to the class into a method like your `public string GetUserBirthday(string month, string day)`, you effectively break the coupling of the `User` class between its data and the operations that work on that data. One of the main ideas of object orientation goes down the drain.

You'll have to either keep your member variables `public` or introduce getters for the fields, so that the caller can use them. Another bad design choice! Such code also violates the [Tell, Don't Ask](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) principle, which states that the class that has the data should work on it, instead of making internal state available to outside classes. Following Tell Don't Ask will lead to better encapsulated code which is easier to reuse.

Your code becomes brittle. You cannot change the implementation of the user's birth date anymore (e.g., by switching it to use a `Date` instead of two separate fields for month and day), without having to touch all callers of the class. The implementation detail has leaked out of the Users class. Your code base will be highly coupled and hard to modify.

As for testing: You have that odd `MyClass` method. Should that be a constructor instead? It should be called `User` then. That `User` constructor takes the birth date, and you can query it with the method without passing parameters, so why not use that? That would lead to a better design and you still can test easily.

When you come to the point in testing, where you cannot check the expected behavior from the outside, take a close look at your code. Maybe the class has gotten too big and there is a new class hidden in there that wants to get out? Consider [refactoring: extract class](https://refactoring.guru/extract-class).

Comment: "As for testing: The User constructor takes the birth date", if you look at his code, there is no `User` constructor.

Comment: @Dan Good point. I read that `MyClass` method as a constructor. I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: His class should be updated to look like the one I provided for it to be a valid `User` POJO

Answer (score 0):

The following class better represents what your trying to accomplish (notice the encapsulation so that your not exposing your representation) :

```
public class User
    {
        private String  birthOfMonth = "";
        private String  birthOfDay = "";

        public User(String month, String day)
        {
          this.birthOfMonth = month;
          this.birthOfDay = day;
        }

        // method 1
        public String getUserBirthday() {
          return birthOfMonth +"/" + birthOfDay;
        }
    }
```

Then to test, setup `User` as follows:

```
User user = new User("August","3rd");
user.getUserBirthday();
... //do actions here
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 would be horribly strange, at least in a simple case like this.

Also, just in case you're really new to Java and don't know this, Java classes start with an upper case. String, not string. Variables and methods are first character lower case. birthOfMonth not BirthOfMonth, getUserBirthday() not GetUserBirthday(). Maybe you know this, but I thought I'd nip that in the bud in case you didn't.